# using custom querystring paypal

Tags: php, paypal, query-string, paypal-ipn, advanced-custom-fields

I have integrated paypal in my application. Everything works good.

I have a minor issue, i want my custom field email as query string on success page to insert more data for that user.

My input coding is below:

```
<input id="custom" name="custom" class="form_textbox"/>
```

And my redirect is as below:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://myweburl.com/ticket.php?tck=test@email.com">
```

But its not passing dynamically. I want to pass email entered in input "custom" to this query string. I know may be the solutions will be basic, but i tried everything, but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that that certain characters need to be [encoded for URLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). At a minimum, you should be encoding the `?` question mark in your return value. It also may not be a bad idea to encode the slashes `/`.

For example, here are some characters that may need to be encoded in your example:

```
?  =     %3F
/  =     %2F
```

You can take reference other encoded characters [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), or try Googling.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. But i just need a simple code t pass custom value as querystring.